# how to add comma in UILabel value in thousands

Tags: iphone, ios, uilabel

I have UILabel in which i show float value i want that if value is in thousand like $1000.00
then label should show $1,000.00

Using following way my code shows

$1000.00

```
        labelOne.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"$ %.2f",f_Cost_of_Vacination_NV];
```

Comment: Why did you duplicate your previous question? The answer I gave in that question covers this.

Comment: but it does not add $ sign

Comment: Then change the `NSNumberFormatter` to `NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle`. Please take some time to look at the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the Number style Currency.this might solve your problem use NSNumberFormatter... and use this line to set currency style

```
NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle.
```

See this

```
NSNumber *number=[[NSNumber alloc]initWithInt:1000];


    NSString *No = [NSNumberFormatter localizedStringFromNumber:number numberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    NSLog(@"%@", No);

    UILabel * text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",No];

    NSLog(@"%@",text);
```

Comment: how to do this please share me some help

Comment: Why are you using `stringWithFormat`? And why are you assigning an `NSString` object to a variable of type `UILabel`?

Comment: I want to remove .00. Is there any property for that?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use [NSNumberFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
NSString *formatted = [NSNumberFormatter localizedStringFromNumber:@(f_Cost_of_Vacination_NV) numberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
NSLog(@"%@", formatted); // will log it as 1,000.00
```

Comment: The question asks about formatting currency values.

Comment: @rmaddy fixed for currency values..

Comment: it gives error @ sign

Comment: Em running the code and it runs flawlessly.. just delete `@` and then rewrite it..

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this :

```
double currency=1000;
    NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] ;
    [numberFormatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    NSString *numberAsString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:currency]];
    NSLog(@" print Converted:%@",numberAsString]);
```

Happy Coding !

Comment: There is no need to use `stringWithFormat` in an `NSLog`. Just do: `NSLog(@" print Converted: %@", numberAsString);`

Comment: Huh? You don't need the embedded `stringWithFormat`. `NSLog` fully support string formats. It's pointless to use `stringWithFormat` in `NSLog`.

Comment: No need for an apology. It seems you changed your previous comment. I'm just trying to be helpful and explain why don't need the extra `stringWithFormat`. Enjoy.

Answer (score -1):

try this one

```
    float value = 200000;
    NSNumberFormatter * formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
    [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    [formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2]; // Set this if you need 2 digits
    NSString * newString =  [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:value]];

 labelOne.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"$ %@",newString];
```

Comment: Why not use the `NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle` instead?